# Inhouse and Adhoc Option Not Available?

Tags: ios, ios-provisioning

I am the admin of our IOS Enterprise Developer program.
But i am unable to see `Inhouse` and `Adhoc` Option.
Instead I can only see `Appstore` and `Adhoc` Option.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

First of all your developer account must be of type "iOS Enterprise Program". If this is the case then the inHouse Options will be in "Provisioning Profile" not certificate.

[image]

Comment: I cant find there too i have attached the Pic of that.

Comment: Did you select right team?  On right top "Peacock Engineering" > "Change Team"

Comment: Thats my account. And the things i can create Using Xcode are IOS Developement and IOS Distribution and i am unable to create a Developer ID distribution or Developer ID Installer Distribution.

Comment: I think your account is not member of Enterprise team.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Check your account Membership in Program Summary, i think its not "IOS Enterprise Program".

Answer (score -1):

The problem is that you're signed in as an Admin. Only the team **Agent** can access the Distribution resources and capabilities in an Enterprise account.